# How to add title attribute when a page has a particular template

Tags: wordpress, templates, attributes

in my admin page i can change the default template page to another custom template.
What i need is:

In my nav header menu i have many links and i have to set title attribute of `a` tag when the `a` tag point to a page that will be rendered with my custom template and not with the default one. Example:

```
<li><a hreh=".." title="myCustom">link1</a></li> //this title will be redirected with my custom template
<li><a hreh="..">link2</a></li> //this title will be redirected with default template
<li><a hreh="..">link3</a></li> //this title will be redirected with default template
<li><a hreh=".." title="myCustom">link4</a></li> //this title will be redirected with my custom template
```

If i open `header.php` that links are created by:

```
<?php $params = array( 
      'theme_location'  =>'primary',
      'limit'  => 5,
      'format' => 'custom',
      'link_before' => '<span>',
      'link_after'  => '</span>' );
       wp_nav_menu($params); 
?>
```

How can i check if link is rendered by default template or by mine one?

Comment: i try to be more clear editing the post.. just a moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but about the `title` thing, you can easily add that at backend... Appearance > Menus. A sample image below..

[image]

---

I'm not sure if this will help but have you tried reading [Creating Your Own Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)?

So that when you create a page, you can choose what template to use for that certain page. Like this image below,

[image]

Comment: I know that i can do this manually.. but i was trying to do automatically... if page is rendered by my custom template ->set title=...

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is using the function *[body_class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class)*, like **`<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`**, your Html is already printing what you need to target elements only in that page:

[image: body classes]

This page is using the template file: `/twentytwelve/page-templates/front-page.php`.

You see there's a StackOverflow class there ;), and that's by:

```
add_filter('body_class', 'body_class_so_14302462');

function body_class_so_14302462( $classes ) 
{
    global $post;
    if( 'page' != $post->post_type )
        return $classes;

    $classes[] = 'STACKOVERFLOW';
    return $classes;
}
```

Instead of adding a class to the array, you could completely override it using `$classes = 'custom-and-only-class';`, and also do all kind of checks to fine tune the output.